# How many parts in the partitions of n are equal to k?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

By partition, I mean a set of positive whole numbers (order doesn't matter, there can be duplicates) that sum to n, each member in that set is called a part.

Let $p(n)=$ the number of partitions for n.

Let $p(n,k)=$ the number of parts in all the partitions of n who are equal to k.

For instance if n=4, we have (4),(3,1),(2,2),(2,1,1),(1,1,1,1).

Then $p(n)=5$

$p(n,1)=7, p(n,2)=3, p(n,3)=1, p(n,4)=1$

Note that $p(n)=\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n k*p(n,k)}{n}$

I am interested in any fun things we can say about $p(n,k)$, including recursive formulas. I doubt there is a closed form solution, as there doesn't seam to be one for $p(n)$. Ramanujan, Hardy and Littlewood came up with a great asymptotic formulas with "the circle method".

Since we can add a k to any partition of $n-k$, we have:

$p(n,k)=p(n-k) + p(n-k,k)$

If $k>n-k$, then $p(n-k,k)=0$ since you can't have a part be greater than the final sum.

Comment: What do you mean by "a partition"?

Comment: I'm really not understanding what you want to know.  Would you please expand upon and clarify your question?  When you do so, you'll find that people will react much better if you explain in the text why this question matters to you, **what efforts you've made to solve it yourself**, and where you're encountering a roadblock to understanding.

Comment: Actually "a list of positive numbers that sum to $n$" (implying that order counts, as $[1,2,3]$ and $[3,2,1]$ are different lists) is called a **composition** of $n$.  In a [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) the order doesn't count.

Comment: According to what distribution are the partitions chosen randomly?

Comment: Changed description to remove need for "picking a partition/part randomly"... make more sense?

Comment: $p(n,1)$ is [OEIS sequence A000070](https://oeis.org/A000070), the partial sums of the partition numbers.
$p(n,2)$ to $p(n,10)$ are OEIS sequences [A024786](https://oeis.org/A024786) to
[A024794](https://oeis.org/A024794).  There are various identities and asymptotic formulas there.